# Issue reading parameterized argument in Jenkins

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a Jenkins job with the following arguments variable.

source_host(String parameter) dest_user(choice parameter) backup (checkbox parameter)

I'm passing the Jenkins arguments to Jenkins Execute Shell as below:

```
$ANSIBLE_SCRIPT_HOME/transfer.sh -a $source_host -b $dest_user -c $backup
```

Below is the transfer.sh script.

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do

  case $opt in

    a) source_host="$OPTARG"

    ;;

    b) dest_user="$OPTARG"

    ;;

    c) isbkup="$OPTARG"

    ;;

    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2

    ;;

  esac

done

printf "Argument source_host is %s\n" "$source_host"

printf "Argument dest_user is %s\n" "$dest_user"

printf "Argument backup is %s\n" "$backup"
```

> Jenkins version: Jenkins 2.138.1 core and libraries
>
> Multiple security vulnerabilities in Jenkins 2.145 and earlier, and
>   LTS 2.138.1 and earlier

If i do not  choose dest_user(choice parameter) i.e blank and invoke the execute shell the output of transfer.sh shows incorrect entry for $dest_user

> Argument source_host is user1
>
> **Argument dest_user is -c**
>
> Argument backup is no

I was expecting dest_user to print nothing in the output instead of -c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "dest_user" is empty or even blank, $dest_user 'goes away' and -c becomes the value to the -b argument.  I think you might want to try

```
$ANSIBLE_SCRIPT_HOME/transfer.sh -a "$source_host" -b "$dest_user" -c "$backup"
```

Then, if $dest_user is empty, you are passing an empty string as a parameter.  The difference is:

```
/path/to/ansible/transfer.sh -a source_host_value -b -c backup_value
```

vs.

```
/path/to/ansible/transfer.sh -a "source_host_value" -b "" -c "backup_value"
```

Putting your script into x.sh, I got:

```
prompt> $ ./x.sh -a a -b b -c c
Argument source_host is a
Argument dest_user is b
Argument backup is c

prompt> $ ./x.sh -a a -b -c c
Argument source_host is a
Argument dest_user is -c
Argument backup is

prompt> $ ./x.sh -a "a" -b "" -c "c"
Argument source_host is a
Argument dest_user is
Argument backup is c
```

Comment: Thanks it helped !!